# How to find out if the elements in one list are in another?

Tags: python, list, element

I have two lists:

```
A = [[2, 5, 13, 14], [4, 5, 10, 12], [2, 9, 10, 11], [2, 5, 12, 13], [4, 5, 6, 12]]
B = [12, 5]
```

I'm trying to find out which lists in A contain the elements in B (order doesn't matter) and get rid of the rest of the lists.

In this case the answers is:

```
[[4, 5, 10, 12], [2, 5, 12, 13], [4, 5, 6, 12]]
```

If we change B and make it `B = [13]`, the answer would be:

```
[[2, 5, 13, 14], [2, 5, 12, 13]]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `set.issubset` with a list comprehension, using `A[:]` will change the original/list object A:

```
A = [[2, 5, 13, 14], [4, 5, 10, 12], [2, 9, 10, 11], [2, 5, 12, 13], [4, 5, 6, 12]]
B = [12, 5]
st = set(B)

A [:] = [sub for sub in A if st.issubset(sub)]

print(A)
[[4, 5, 10, 12], [2, 5, 12, 13], [4, 5, 6, 12]]
```

Same for B = [13]

```
A = [[2, 5, 13, 14], [4, 5, 10, 12], [2, 9, 10, 11], [2, 5, 12, 13], [4, 5, 6, 12]]
B = [13]
st = set(B)

A [:] = [sub for sub in A if st.issubset(sub)]

print(A)
[[2, 5, 13, 14], [2, 5, 12, 13]]
```

[set objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects)

> s.issubset(t)  s <= t  test whether every element in s is in t

For very large A or if you have memory restrictions you can use a generator expression:

```
A [:] = (sub for sub in A if st.issubset(sub))
```

If order never matters and it is possible to sets I would suggest you using them from the very beginning. Doing lookups on sets will be a lot more efficient.

Some timings on a slightly larger A:

```
In [23]: A = [[2, 5, 13, 14], [4, 5, 10, 12], [2, 9, 10, 11], [2, 5, 12, 13], [4, 5, 6, 12],[2, 5, 13, 14], [4, 5, 10, 12], [2, 9, 10, 11], [2, 5, 12, 13], [4, 5, 6, 12],[2, 5, 13, 14], [4, 5, 10, 12], [2, 9, 10, 11], [2, 5, 12, 13], [4, 5, 6, 12]]

In [24]: B = [12, 5]                                 
In [25]: timeit  filter(lambda x: all(y in x for y in B), A)
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.45 µs per loop

In [26]: %%timeit                                    
st = set(B)
[sub for sub in A if st.issubset(sub)]
   ....: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.88 µs per loop
 map(lambda x: not B_set-set(x), A)
In [27]: %%timeit
....: B_set = set(B)
....: map(lambda x: not B_set-set(x), A)
....: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.95 µs per loop
```

If you already had the elements stored as sets in A:

```
In [33]: %%timeit                             
st = set(B)
[sub for sub in A if sub >= st]
....: 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.12 µs per loop
```

Comment: Are deleting other users answers ? (not mine)

Comment: @PedroLobito. I don't know what you mean?

Comment: a lot of answers where deleted on this answer.

Comment: @PedroLobito. yes, but I still don't know what you mean?

Comment: @Pedro: beyond a certain level of rep you can see who deleted an answer.  I assure you every answer was deleted by its own author.

Comment: Sorry about my question, thank you for confirming that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` in combination with `all` here:

```
print filter(lambda x: all(y in x for y in B), A)
```

A bit more efficient answer:

```
B_set = set(B)
print map(lambda x: not B_set-set(x), A)
```